# Show that clu($B$) = empty set in a metric space $M$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A$ be contained in $M$ such that $A$ is non-empty but clu($A$) is the empty set. Assume $A$ does not equal $M$. Let $y$ be an element of $M-A$ and let $B=A \cup \{y\}$. Show that clu($B$) is the empty set.

clu is the cluster point

If I am thinking about this right, $M-A$ is everything in $M$ that isn't in $A$ right?
Then the union of $y$ and $B$ just ends up being $M$ doesn't it?

Comment: clu(A) means what? I don't recognize the usage.

Comment: Can you define ${\rm clu}(A)$, please? I don't recall ever seeing this notation. And since you say that $A \neq \varnothing$, I assume that ${\rm clu}$ does not mean "closure", otherwise we'd have $A \subseteq {\rm cl}(A) = \varnothing \implies A = \varnothing$.

Comment: its what it says on the problem. I was hoping someone would recognize what it means....i've looked through my notes and can't find anything that uses it

Comment: By $\mathrm{clu}(A)$ you mean the set of all cluster points of $A$?

Comment: I think that might be it. I'm still trying to find it in my notes

Comment: clu is the cluster point yes

Answer (score 1):

You have $A$ a subset of $M$ which has no cluster points. Then the problem assumes that $A$ is not $M$ so that is why a point $y$ in $M-A$, or more simply a point which is in $M$ but not in $A,$ may be chosen. The problem is then defining $B$ by taking $A$ and throwing in the extra point $y.$ In this case $B$ doesn't need to end up being all of $M$ (although it might be, if it happened that at the start $A$ contained all points of $M$ excepting for $y$).

Now note that a cluster point $z$ of a subset $C$ of $M$ must have a sequence of *pairwise distinct* elements of $C-\{z\}$ which converges to $z.$ Applying this to $C=B=A \cup {y},$ any such sequence of pairwise distinct terms from $B$ would eventually contain only elements of $A$ (since $y$ can only appear once). But then $A$ has a cluster point after all.

Comment: I am confused on where z comes from in this. Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: The use of $z$ here is just as a notation for a supposed cluster point of a general subset $C$ of the metric space $M$. [I called that $C$ so as not to confuse with either of already considered sets $A,B.$] Also note that the sequence of distinct points which approach $z$ must be points from $C$ in order that $z$ be a cluster point. Let me know if you need other details...

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure how to write this out as a proof

Comment: That's the hardest part for me is how to write it out and have it make sense

Comment: @Daniel If you can follow the outline in this answer, I think all you need to do is to fill in the descriptions, in your own words, of how it all fits together. Sometimes looking at proofs already done in the text you're using (or another text) can give a good idea of how to write up a proof of something.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try! Thank you!